# My events in Calendar are stack in same date, but my events have different dates

Tags: jquery, events, fullcalendar, thymeleaf

Hello everyone I am stuck at this calendar.
I need to display my events in calendar. I have only one event it displays fine, but when I have two more events my events are stored in same date! Although they have different date. 
I am retrieving may events in database..

This is my jQuery code:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/

var events = [];
var myObject = new Object();
var theList = [[${appointments}]]

$(document).ready(function(){

    for (var i = 0; i < theList.length; i++) {
        myObject.title = theList[i].title;
        myObject.start = new Date(theList[i].start);
        myObject.requestNumber = theList[i].requestNumber;
        myObject.locationId = theList[i].locationId;
        myObject.arrivalTime = theList[i].arrivalTime;
        myObject.admissionDate = new Date(theList[i].admissionDate);
        myObject.procedureDate = "-";
        myObject.admittingDiagnosisDesc = theList[i].admittingDiagnosisDesc;
        myObject.description = "";
        events.push(myObject);
    }

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultView: 'month',
        header: {
            left: '',
            center: 'title'
        },
        editable: false,
        selectable: true,
        events: events,
        dayClick: function() {
           // alert('a day has been clicked!');
        },
        eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
            showAppointmentDetails(event)
        }
    });
});

/*]]>*/
```

This is my output(fullcalendar_events_are_stored_in_same_date):

[image]

Events have different start date but they are stored in same date. Need help...

Comment: @salman can you help me?

Comment: what is the length of `theList` at the beginning (when the page loads)

Comment: @salman 3.. It has different start date.

Comment: i have a suggestion, but i am not sure. Your code should work well for 1 event, but from 2 or more u should face with a problem. am i right?

Comment: Yes, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-initialise myObject as a new object each time you loop, otherwise you're overwriting the same object in memory with new values each time the loop runs.

The object is stored in the array as a reference (rather than a copy), so when this array is passed to the calendar, it reads the items in the array and finds they are identical, because they all reference the same source object in memory. Hence why it looks like all your events are on the same day. If you examined them you'd find that all their properties are identical, not just the date.

Simply do it like this instead:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < theList.length; i++) {
    var myObject = new Object(); //create a new object each time
    myObject.title = theList[i].title;
    myObject.start = new Date(theList[i].start);
    myObject.requestNumber = theList[i].requestNumber;
    myObject.locationId = theList[i].locationId;
    myObject.arrivalTime = theList[i].arrivalTime;
    myObject.admissionDate = new Date(theList[i].admissionDate);
    myObject.procedureDate = "-";
    myObject.admittingDiagnosisDesc = theList[i].admittingDiagnosisDesc;
    myObject.description = "";
    events.push(myObject);
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/50/ gives a working example.

However, having said all that, it's not really clear why you really need that `for` loop at all? I get the impression from the code that your events are largely in the correct format anyway. Apart from `description` and `procedureDate`, into which you just push default values, the loop is just making an exact copy of the same data and putting it into a new array.

I think you can just supply "theList" direct to fullCalendar in the "events" parameter, and get the same result. See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/51/